# Given the product is measurable, is each factor measurable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Given a random variable $M$ on $(\Omega,\mathscr F, \Bbb P)$ and $M=X\cdot Y$, can we proof that $X$ and $Y$ are also measurable?

To be more specific, I was thinking about if a process $M_t=X_t\cdot Y_t$ is adapted to its natural filtration $\mathscr F_t^M$. Is $X_t$ and $Y_t$ also adapted to the natural filtration?

Thanks for any thought.

Comment: Hmm, you could have $M \equiv 0$ while $X$ and $Y$ are nonmeasurable and supported on disjoint sets

Comment: I was thinking $M$ is identically $0$, so $M^{-1}(0) = \Omega$

Comment: @JairTaylor Thanks. I was thinking, let's say $X(A)=1$ and $X(A^c)=0$ and $Y(A)=0$ and $Y(A^c)=1$ for some subset $A$ of $\Omega$. The product M is always 0, and set $\mathscr F=\left{\empty,\Omega \right}$. M is measurable regarding $mathscr F$ but Y and X are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; not necessarily.

Witness a sample space, $(\Omega,\mathcal F) =\big( \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)\},\{\emptyset, \{(1,1)\}, \{(1,2),(2,1)\}, \Omega\}\big)$.

We define the random variables $X:(x,y)\mapsto x$, $Y:(x,y)\mapsto y, M:(x,y)\mapsto xy$.

Then $M(\omega)=[X\cdot Y] (\omega)$, and $M$ is $\mathcal F$-measureable, but neither $X$ nor $Y$ are.

- $M^{-1}\{1\}= \{(1,1)\}\in \mathcal F\\M^{-1}\{2\}=\{(1,2),(2,1)\}\in \mathcal F$
- $X^{-1}\{1\}= \{(1,1),(1,2)\}\notin \mathcal F\\X^{-1}\{2\}=\{(2,1)\}\notin \mathcal F$
- $Y^{-1}\{1\}= \{(1,1),(2,1)\}\notin \mathcal F\\Y^{-1}\{2\}=\{(1,2)\}\notin \mathcal F$

So $M$ being $\mathcal F$-measurable and $M=X\cdot Y$ is insufficient to prove that either $X$ or $Y$ are $\mathcal F$-measurable.